# Nonempty sets Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

### Textbook Question:

[image]

### Textbook Solution:

[image]

### For part a) and d)  :

- What is the mathematical proof to show that the set is an empty set or nonempty set ?

Comment: Well, for $a$), say, argue that for any natural number we must have $2x+7>3$.

Comment: You mean that fact that natural numbers only include 0 and positive integers, but if we do 2x = 3 -7 and then x = -4/2 , x = -2, so it is wrong, and we consider it an empty set ?

Comment: If your point is that there are integer solutions to that equation, then you are certainly correct.  But $-2\notin \mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $\{x\in S: P(x)\}$ what we mean is "the set of all numbers, $x$, such that $x$ is an element of $x$ and property $P$ holds for $x$. This set is non-empty if there is at least one such number. In your case, the properties are always either equations, or equations combined with the assertion that the number falls in a certain set (though more generally they don't have to be), and so the set is non-empty precisely when there is a solution to the equation.

The first set is the set of all $x$ such that $x$ is in $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and $2x+7=3$. We can solve the equation using algebra to find out that the only solution is $x=-2$, which is not a natural number. Thus there are no numbers, x, in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $2x+7=3$. Therefore $\{x|x\in\mathbb{N},2x+7=3\}=\emptyset$.

The fourth set is the set of all $x$ such that $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+4=6$. Again doing algebra tells us that there are two solutions, $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{2}$. Both of these are real numbers, and so $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x^2+4=6\}=\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$ which is non-empty.

Comment: exactly. Set A includes a x = negative integer while natural numbers can only include positive integers. Thus, x = -2 cannot be in set A, and then the set is empty. However, x = $sqrt2$ is in set D, so that is why the set is non-empty. Thanks for your info.

Comment: @Kourosh That's correct. Similar reasoning applies to the other problems: find solutions to the equations and then check to see if they fall in the demarcated sets.

Comment: By demarcated sets, you mean R, N, Z, etc ? Or a set of numbers that we have created by ourselves like A: {1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 10} ?

Comment: @Kourosh It depends on the problem. We could certainly look at $\{x\in A|x ^2 = 121\}$ and discover that it is $\{12\}$, but none of these problems have asked you to do that.

Comment: Ok I see, it depends on the type of question.